# I am facing issue with tkinter button style "_tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name a"

Tags: python, button, tkinter, ttk

I was trying to do a exercise on making a onscreen keyboard using `tkinter` and I almost completed the program and it works fine but the issue is when I was doing some last minute touch-ups like setting a style for key I encountered an error.

```
style=ttk.Style()
style.configure("mybutton.TButton", font=("montserrat", "10", "bold"), 
                foreground="white", background="green")
style.configure("myBigbutton.TButton", font=("monserrat", "24", "bold"), 
                foreground="white", background="green")
style.map("myButton.TButton", background=('active', 'green'))
```

I'm defining two different styles for two different kinds of buttons and when I use this `map` condition I'm getting an error `_tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name a`. If I change  `active` to `pressed` I will get
`_tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name p` as error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation of the [`Style.map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.map) method,

> Each key in *kw* is an option and each value should be a list or a tuple (usually) containing statespecs grouped in tuples, lists, or some other preference.

Which simply means you need to **nest** the value of the statespecs — each of which is sequence — for the `background` keyword inside an outer `list` or `tuple` *even when there is only one*.

In other words, you need to write the value as shown below:

```
style.map("myButton.TButton", background=[('active', 'green')])
```